# Void Parameters in C

Tags: c, parameters, pthreads, void

I am using pthreads and am using a function called 'runner' to specify which methods to use on the threads.

Here is my runner function:

```
void *runner(void* param){
    int* parm = (int*) param;

if(parm == 1){
    MergeSort(intArr, 0, (fileLen/2));
}

if(parm == 2){
    MergeSort(intArr, (fileLen/2)+1, fileLen - 1);
}
if(parm == 3){
    Merge(intArr, 0, (fileLen/2), fileLen - 1);

}
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

My problem is when I create this thread in main, I get a compiler error: "warning: comparison between pointer and integer".

```
pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, 1);
```

I've been trying different ways to cast the integer but I'm still struggling to find the correct way.

Comment: `parm` is a pointer, and `1` is an integer. `parm == 1` is ill-formed.  (Some compilers, as an extension, will treat this as checking to see if `parm` points to memory address 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_create` expects a `void*` for its fourth argument, corresponding to the `void*` input to `runner`, but you're passing it an `int`. Instead, create an `int` variable and pass its *address* as the fourth argument, for example:

```
int param = 1;
pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, &param);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first approach would be to

1. Create an `int` object `param` that holds the value you want to pass.
2. Obtain a pointer to that object: `&param`
3. Convert that `int *` pointer to `void *` pointer.
4. Pass that `void *` pointer to `pthread_create`

I.e. when creating thread, do

```
int param = 1;
int *pparam = &param;
void *vpparam = (void *) pparam;
pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, vpparam);
```

The above can be compacted into

```
int param = 1;
pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, &param);
```

which does the same thing.

Now, in the thread function we have to do everything in reverse

1. Receive that `void *` pointer in thread function
2. Convert the received `void *` pointer to `int *` type
3. Dereference the pointer to retrieve the `int` value

So, in thread function we do

```
void *runner(void* param) {
  int *pparam = (int *) param;
  int parm = *pparam;

  if (parm == 1){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

or, more compactly

```
void *runner(void* param) {
  int parm = *(int *) param;
  ...
```

Note that in this approach the thread function will dereference a pointer to access that very same `int param` object we created before the `pthread_create` call. It is generally important to keep that `int` object alive as long as the thread runs.

---

Alternatively, you might try a more "hackerish" approach: convert the desired `int` value to `void *` type and pass it directly to `pthread_create`

```
void *vparam = (void *) (uintptr_t) 1;
pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, vparam);
```

and in thread function convert the received `void *` pointer back to `int` type

```
void *runner(void* param) {
  int parm = (int) (uintptr_t) param;

  if(parm == 1){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The former approach is intuitively cleaner and generally more extensible, if one day you'll want to pass something heavier than a mere `int`.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful, rather than just corrected code.

Comment: Will the first approach screw up if the launching code reaches the next `}` (deallocating `param`) before the thread reads it?

Comment: Accessing an automatic variable from a different thread is implementation defined. I think the best (read:portable) option is to use an allocated var.

Comment: @2501: "Accessing an automatic variable from a different thread is implementation defined". Would you please provide a link to the corresponding part of the specification? And what specification would that be, I wonder: C11, POSIX or something else?

Comment: Sure: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.4. p5

Comment: @2501: Thanks. However, it should be noted that such statements in C11 apply to C11 threads only. They do not apply to POSIX threads (and the above is a well-established technique in POSIX thread programming). Of course, once we start using POSIX threads, we are already deep into the "implementation-defined" area.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying different ways to cast the integer but I'm still struggling to find the correct way

Try this:
`pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, (void*)(intptr_t)1);`

and in the thread function:

```
    void *runner(void* param){
        int parm = (int)(intptr_t)param;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function takes a void*, a void pointer. In C a void pointer is used to point at an unspecified type in memory. It was what was used for generics before C++ invented templating

```
  std::vector<int> vector;
```

Since the argument is a pointer as AnT said you should pass the function a pointer. The code above looks like it works. If you want you can just cast

```
   pthread_create(&tid1, &attr1, runner, (void*)1);
```